# How to use java lambda expression foreach to add to an existing list

Tags: apache-spark, lambda, java-8

I want to implement the below functionality as Java8 Lambda

```
private StructType getSchema(Dataset<Row> df, List<String> cols){
        StructType schema = df.schema();
        for (String col: cols){
            schema.add(col, "int", true);
        }
        return schema;
    }
```

when i try to use the below code

```
 private StructType getSchema(Dataset<Row> df, List<String> cols){
        StructType schema = df.schema();
        cols.forEach(col -> schema = schema.add(col, "int", true));
        return schema;
    }
```

I am getting compilation error

```
variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final.
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: why do you need to assign? `schema = schema.add(col, "int", true)`

Comment: ohh yes, you are right i can directly add and return the schema. Thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning (for whatever reason) that schema, simply don't:

```
private StructType getSchema(Dataset<Row> df, List<String> cols){
    StructType schema = df.schema();
    cols.forEach(col -> schema.add(col, "int", true));
    return schema;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Final or effectively final" means that if a variable is declared outside the lambda expression (like your `schema` is), then you can read it, or call methods on it, but **not** assign to it.

The javadoc for [StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html) suggests that `StructType` is an immutable class where the `add` method returns a new instance, so `forEach` is probably the wrong kind of iteration to use here. Your original for-in is actually a better choice.